# How to change display of variable products on Woocommerce archive-product page

Tags: woocommerce, storefront

I am using the Storefront theme (downloaded a few days ago so newest version) and I want to do something quite simple: 
**on the archive-product page I want to display the product name of a list of variable products (all shoes) , along with two custom fields that I attached to the product post type.**

All goes well with simple products. I can edit that which is shown through my theme-child folder/woocommerce/loop/price.php.
My issue appears as soon as I turn a product into a variable product. When I do that, the custom fields disappear, and all I see beneath the product is a button that says "select option"

I have been looking for hours to find the correct template/hook to fix this but I just cant find it...
I have no idea where to look :( Hope ome

Comment: Please sbhow us your code, that you have tried till now.

Comment: Allright, but like I said this code stops working as soon as I change the product to variable...
`
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;
?>

<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
 <p><?php the_field('artiestnaam') ?></p>
 <p><?php the_field('naamschilderij') ?></p>
 <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>

<?php endif; ?>
`

Comment: geez why do they make it so hard to get a decent code syntax display.... Would you know how to get a decent format?

Comment: Please post the code directly in your post rather than as a comment